# Can't load resource, always returns null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, java-8, illegalstateexception

I have the following problem:

I am developing a Java 8 Application with IntelliJ IDEA 15 using JavaFX as GUI and Gradle as build automation system (never worked with Gradle before though). I always get an `IllegalStateException` "Location is not set" when loading the fxml file, the reason is because `getClass().getResource("gui.fxml")` always returns `null`.

My Java Code:

```
package minerva.gui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml")==null); // DEBUG: always returns true, but why?

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Minerva");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        Controller control = loader.getController();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Maybe Gradle is responsible for this, I don't know.

build.gradle:

```
group 'minerva.impl'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'minerva'
```

I also checked the resource patterns in the settings of IntelliJ, they should be valid: !?*.java;!?*.form;!?*.class;!?*.groovy;!?*.scala;!?*.flex;!?*.kt;!?*.clj;!?*.aj

And here is also an image of my structure:
[image: Link to the image]

Comment: try with slash getResource("/gui.fxml")

Comment: @AdamSkywalker changing it to getResource("/gui.fxml") and moving it into the resource folder solves the problem, thx

Comment: Has anyone tried this with java 11? it always return null for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle has a similar project structure as maven and seperates between sources and resources. 
Ressources should be put into `src/main/resources`.

Move your `gui.fxml` file into the `resource` folder and it should be found.

Your resulting artifacts are placed in `$PROJECT/target` and if you have similar problems in the future, it is a good idea to look into your `jar,war,ear` or what ever archive in order to see, if the files are packed up as expected.

Comment: Like I wrote to @AdamSkywalker above: moving the file to the resource folder and changing getResource("gui.fxml") to getResource("/gui.fxml") solves the problem. I also figured out that by adding `sourceSets {main { resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.fxml"]}}}` to `build.gradle` is a possible solution too.